# Typescript is changing type that was inferred

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on a complex generic and one of its parts is not working as expected:

```
// T and U are changed 
type Type<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U extends object ? Array<U> : T : never;
```

Inffered type `U` become `UnionMember1[] | UnionMember2[]` instead of expected `(UnionMember1 | UnionMember2)[]`:

```
type Z = { a: string };
type Y = { b: number }

const complex: Array<Z | Y> = [{ a: '1'}, { b: 1 }];

// Type '({ a: string; } | { b: number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Z[] | Y[]'.
const complexChild: Type<typeof complex> = [{ a: '1'}, { b: 1 }];
```

Another curious part (but can be completely covered by fixing the case with inferred type) is that `T` has changed:

```
const primitive: Array<string | number> = ['1', 1];

// Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type '(string[] & (string | number)[]) | (number[] & (string | number)[])'.
const primitiveChild: Type<typeof primitive> = ['1', 1];
```

Any suggstions how to fix that? Thanks!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEBVQQwOwE1AVWgJwKagMYAtYHM0EAoAFwE8AHDcStAHnAD5QBeCUNADxLXgGdQAQRQooZOgEsYAMzQokzAPxIO3XnAEB7AEYArNJhKhlw0eMTMAXO2sw0ANzkBuIq-JVQALVagA3tGs+EhQpPFAAXxd3DABNH39tWwBXAFttOQjXTE0YIKxNFIoAGy5rUzE6bwAfUBjmNgBtfyhrAHIARlbwgBo-UETQdoiAXRcibNyjbMKSzgBhbAkiuGsaKjpozWl8ma560CaA0A6u3oTrIfDRrJy8ihCUiRIJRzKRCqCQmDCamFT0lD7BonXrta7jW5Ge4SR7PRwLJYrCC0Da0LagaGwl5oIEgwajIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing here can be explained by the existence of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

When you write `U extends object ? ... : ...` in the generic type `Type` and `U` resolves to a union, each member of the resulting union will be distributed individually to the next statement (in this case `Array<U>`).

You can stop the distibution by wrapping `U` and `object` inside a tuple.

```
type Type<T> = T extends Array<infer U> 
  ? [U] extends [object] 
    ? Array<U> 
    : T 
  : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=2&ssc=87&pln=2&pc=1#code/PTAEBVQQwOwE1AVWgJwKagMYAtYHM0EAoAFwE8AHDcStAHnAD5QBeCUNADxLXgGdQAQRQooZOgEsYAMzQokzAPygA2ogC6HbrzgCVAewBGAKzSYSm5cNHjEzAFztHMNADc5AbiLfyVUAC1WUABvaEc%20EhQpPFAAXy9fDABNINDDZwBXAFtDOTjvTH0YCKx9LIoAGy5HazE6QIAfUCTmNhVQqEcAcgBGLtiAGhDQdNAeuPUvIkLiklLyqs4AYWwJCrhHGio6RP1pecquVtUO7r7B4dHx2MmCopKKKKyJEgl3GpE6iKiYGKaYbK5FDHFS9LpDHq3ab3OaPCTPV7uFZrDYQWg7Wh7UBwhFvNAgsEQyZAA)

Comment: Hilarious! Exactly what I needed. Thanks, that really helped!